# Given H is a subset of G, find all cosets of H in G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

G = U(15) and H = <[4]>

I know U(15) = {1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14} and I need to figure out what H is...
I got H = {[4],[8]} I just don't know if I did that correctly, I did not put [12] in H because 12 is not in U(15)

I need help finding the cosets of H = <[4]> in G = U(15)

Comment: A few things I can say about this question.

1. Learn mathjax.
2. Define your objects
3. Know your definitions!

Comment: Anyways I can roughly gather what each group is supposed to represent. In which case your description of $H$ is wrong. $G$ is a group with binary operation $'\times'$ and thus $H$ should also have it as the binary operation.

Comment: so, H = { [1], [4] } under multiplication?

Comment: Is your question: "Let $G$ be the units of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$ and let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $\{[4]\}$. Is the $H=\{[4],[8]\}$?"

Comment: not exactly, H = cyclic group of  the element [4].

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is a little bit weird. The binary operation in $G$ is multiplication but you are considering $H$ as an additive subgroup. Actually, we can see without any calculation that $H = G$, just observing that $gcd(15,4)=1$.

Comment: yeah, I was using the wrong operation. I got it now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If $G = U(15) = (\Bbb Z_{15})^{\times}$, and the operations is *multiplication* (mod $15$), then:

$H = \langle [4]\rangle = \{[1],[4]\}$, since:

$[4]^2 = [16] = [1]$ since $16-1 = 15 \in 15\Bbb Z$.

You might want to re-think what you have done so far.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this out. I got four different cosets. Thanks for the help!